# Download report from jsreport and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, excel, jsreport

I'd like to know how could I make a report downloadable from my AngularJS Application?

The report is a `.xlsx` I can post the data, but the response is:
[image: response]

What I'd like is a downloadable file, or to open the `.xlsx` on Excel Online in other tab as in the preview.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I usually recommend to create a hidden form and do plain http submit to jsreport /api/report. This is the most stable way and works across all browsers.

```
<form method='POST' target='_blank' action='/api/report' id='jsrForm'>
    <input hidden='true' name='template[shortid]' value="41ucBgXKe"/>
    <input hidden='true' name='data[foo]' value="Hello world"/>
    <input hidden='true' name='options[Content-Disposition]' value="attachment; filename=myreport.pdf"/>
</form>



<script>
    document.getElementById("jsrForm").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Does this open the report on other tab? how could I directly open the `.xlsx` at Excel Online?

Comment: This will open a download dialog. To open excel online you can remove Content-Disposition and add options[preview] with value true. But be aware that this will proxy excel online through public jsreport server. https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport/issues/130

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the response? If so, add the content-disposition header and MediaType header to the response:

For System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage{Content = ...........}
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
                    FileName = "mydoc.xlsx"
                };    
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

For System.Net.WebClient

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "attachment");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```